# Glmnet is different with intercept=TRUE compared to intercept=FALSE and with penalty.factor=0 for an intercept in x

Tags: r, glmnet

I am new to glmnet and playing with the penalty.factor option. The vignette says that it "Can be 0 for some variables, which implies no shrinkage, and that variable is always included in the model." And [the longer PDF document](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf) has code. So I expected that running a regression with `intercept = TRUE` and no constant in `x` would be the same as with `intercept = FALSE` and a constant in `x` with `penalty.factor = 0`. But the code below shows that it is not: the latter case has an intercept of 0 and the other two coefficients are 20% larger than in the former.

```
library("glmnet")

set.seed(7)

# penalty for the intercept
intercept_penalty <- 0

# Simulate data with 2 features
num_regressors <- 2
num_observations <- 100
X <- matrix(rnorm(num_regressors * num_observations),
            ncol = num_regressors,
            nrow = num_observations)

# Add an intercept in the right-hand side matrix: X1 = (intercept + X)
X1 <- cbind(matrix(1, ncol = 1, nrow = num_observations), X)

# Set random parameters for the features
beta <- runif(1 + num_regressors)

# Generate observations for the left-hand side
Y <- X1 %*% beta + rnorm(num_observations) / 10

# run OLS
ols <- lm(Y ~ X)
coef_ols <- coef(ols)

# Run glmnet with an intercept in the command, not in the matrix
fit <- glmnet(y = Y,
              x = X,
              intercept = T,
              penalty.factor = rep(1, num_regressors),
              lambda = 0)
coef_intercept_equal_true <- coef(fit)

# run glmnet with an intercept in the matrix with a penalty
# factor of intercept_penalty for the intercept and 1 for the rest
fit_intercept_equal_false <- glmnet(y = Y,
              x = X1,
              intercept = F,
              penalty.factor = c(intercept_penalty, rep(1, num_regressors)),
              lambda = 0)
coef_intercept_equal_false <- coef(fit_intercept_equal_false)

# Compare all three methods in a data frame
# For lasso_intercept_equal_false, the index starts at 2 because
# position 1 is reserved for intercepts, which is missing in this case
comparison <- data.frame(original = beta,
                         ols = coef_ols,
                         lasso_intercept_equal_true = coef_intercept_equal_true[1:length(coef_intercept_equal_true)],
                         lasso_intercept_equal_false = coef_intercept_equal_false[2:length(coef_intercept_equal_false)]
)

comparison$difference <- comparison$lasso_intercept_equal_false - comparison$lasso_intercept_equal_true
comparison
```

Furthermore, the discrepancy for this example is the same with different penalty factors for the intercept term, whether `intercept_penalty` equals 0, 1, 3000, -10, etc. The discrepancy is similar with a positive penalty, e.g. `lambda = 0.01`.

If this is not a bug, what is the proper usage of penalty.factor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted the author, who confirmed that this is a bug and added that it is on his list of bug fixes. In the meantime, a workaround is to center the regressors, e.g. with

```
fit_centered <- glmnet(y = Y,
                       x = scale(X1, T, F),
                       intercept = F,
                       lambda = 0)
```

And in this case, the penalty factor does not matter. Here is a revised script that compares OLS, LASSO with intercept, LASSO without intercept, and LASSO with centered regressors:

```
library("glmnet")

set.seed(7)

# Simulate data with 2 features
num_regressors <- 2
num_observations <- 100
X <- matrix(rnorm(num_regressors * num_observations),
            ncol = num_regressors,
            nrow = num_observations)

# Add an intercept in the right-hand side matrix: X1 = (intercept + X)
X1 <- cbind(matrix(1, ncol = 1, nrow = num_observations), X)

# Set random parameters for the features
beta <- runif(1 + num_regressors)

# Generate observations for the left-hand side
Y <- X1 %*% beta + rnorm(num_observations) / 10

# run OLS
ols <- lm(Y ~ X)
coef_ols <- coef(ols)

# Run glmnet with an intercept in the command, not in the matrix
fit <- glmnet(y = Y,
              x = X,
              intercept = T,
              penalty.factor = rep(1, num_regressors),
              lambda = 0)
coef_intercept <- coef(fit)

# run glmnet with an intercept in the matrix with a penalty
# factor of 0 for the intercept and 1 for the rest
fit_no_intercept <- glmnet(y = Y,
              x = X1,
              intercept = F,
              lambda = 0)
coef_no_intercept <- coef(fit_no_intercept)

# run glmnet with an intercept in the matrix with a penalty
# factor of 0 for the intercept and 1 for the rest
# If x is centered, it works (even though y is not centered). Center it with:
#   X1 - matrix(colMeans(X1), nrow = num_observations, ncol = 1 + num_regressors, byrow = T)
# or with
# X1_centered = scale(X1, T, F)

fit_centered <- glmnet(y = Y,
                      x = scale(X1, T, F),
                      intercept = F,
                      lambda = 0)
coef_centered <- coef(fit_centered)

# Compare all three methods in a data frame
# For lasso_intercept and the others, the index starts at 2 because
# position 1 is reserved for intercepts, which is missing in this case
comparison <- data.frame(ols = coef_ols,
                         lasso_intercept = coef_intercept[1:length(coef_intercept)],
                         lasso_no_intercept = coef_no_intercept[2:length(coef_no_intercept)],
                         lasso_centered = coef_centered[2:length(coef_centered)]
)


comparison$diff_intercept <- comparison$lasso_intercept - comparison$lasso_no_intercept
comparison$diff_centered <- comparison$lasso_centered - comparison$lasso_intercept
comparison
```

The answer:

```
                  ols lasso_intercept lasso_no_intercept lasso_centered diff_intercept diff_centered
(Intercept) 0.9748302       0.9748302          0.0000000      0.0000000      0.9748302 -9.748302e-01
X1          0.6559541       0.6559541          0.7974851      0.6559541     -0.1415309  2.220446e-16
X2          0.7986957       0.7986957          0.9344306      0.7986957     -0.1357348  4.440892e-16
```

For LASSO with centered regressors, the estimated intercept is 0 but the other coefficients are the same as the LASSO with intercept.

Comment: Two years later... it looks like this behavior is still there. For example, `data(QuickStartExample)`, `fit = glmnet(x, y, intercept=TRUE)` gives a different answer than `x1 <- cbind(1, x)`, `fit1 = glmnet(x1, y, intercept=FALSE)`. It's not completely clear to me why these should be different, however. Doesn't the intercept get special treatment because lasso standardizes the features by necessity? How would it be able to distinguish between a designated intercept and a regular column of ones?